# Copying values from one sheet based on condition to another workbook

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I've written some code that assigns each item in a list a code based on row #.  What I want to do from there is choose a copy all information from each row that corresponds with a chosen code, then paste it to another workbook.  I've been having some trouble.  Here's the code:

```
Sub LSHP_Distribute()

Dim wbLSHP As Workbook
Dim wsLSHP As Worksheet
Dim CodeRange As Range
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim wbTEST As Workbook

Set wbLSHP = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsLSHP = wbLSHP.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Generate codes for newly added items
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                             
'Turn off screen updating

With wsLSHP
    FirstRow = .Range("F3").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    LastRow = .Range("B6", .Range("B6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 5
    Set CodeRange = .Range("$F$" & FirstRow, "$F$" & LastRow)
End With

For Each cell In CodeRange
    If cell = "" Then
        If cell.Row Mod 3 = 0 Then
            cell.Value = "1"
        ElseIf cell.Row Mod 3 = 1 Then
            cell.Value = "2"
        ElseIf cell.Row Mod 3 = 2 Then
            cell.Value = "3"
        Else
        End If
    End If
Next cell

'Open Spreadsheets to Distribute Items
Dim PasteRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Set wbTEST = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="V:\Test.xlsx")

PasteRow = wbTEST.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

Below is where I'm having the problem

```
wbLSHP.Activate
For Each cell In CodeRange
    If cell = "1" Then
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wbTEST.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(PasteRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        PasteRow = PasteRow + 1
    Else
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

First problem is the For loop isn't copying the correct range in "CodeRange", the second problem is it only copies once before I get an Automation Error.  Let me know if you have any questions, or know of a more efficient way to write this code.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Why not move all items to the new workbook then run the code to remove unnecessary items?  SHould save some heartache

Comment: In your last loop causing you the problems, you suddenly refer to the `ActiveCell` but it's not clear what this is. Should it be `cell`? Secondly, after you copy you increment `PasteRow` by 1 but the range you copy is more than one row deep.

Answer (score 0):

Your range is defined to Start in `F3` and end in `BSomething`, but you store to CodeRange only the F column.

```
Set CodeRange = .Range("$F$" & FirstRow, "$F$" & LastRow)
```

Try using:

```
Set CodeRange = .Range("$B$" & FirstRow, "$F$" & LastRow)
```

I suggest instead of Copy and Paste, assign the value to a variable and put the value of the variable on `wbTEST`.